# Check box will not update with a tick from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm creating a form that has two checkboxes yes and no. I have added a yes or no into a mysql field called Completed.

The problem I have is getting the tick boxes to show a tick if the field that has a Yes or a No.

So depending what is in the field Completed "Yes" or "No" the tick boxes should be ticked or not ticked.

My code is like this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="Completed" Completed="Yes" value="<?php echo $stuff["Completed"]; ?>" <?php echo $stuff["Completed"] ? 'checked=" checked"' : ''; ?> > Yes</td>`

`<input type="checkbox" name="Completed" Completed="No" value="<?php echo $stuff["Completed"]; ?>" <?php echo $stuff["Completed"] ? 'checked=" checked"' : ''; ?> > No</td>`

Comment: So what's the issue? What does the generated HTML show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check boxes don't strike me as an appropriate control for this type of information.  Have you considered using radio buttons instead?  In any case, the answer to your question depends on how you are storing the data in the database.  If it is a simple "Yes" or "No", then try something like the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="Completed" value="Yes" <?php echo $stuff["Completed"] == 'Yes' ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
```

Comment: Agree radio buttons are better especially for this type of option where a user could check both yes and no in error

Comment: Brilliant worked perfectly :) Thank you. Thank you for the Radio advice.

Answer (score 2):

`<?php echo $stuff["Completed"] ? 'checked=" checked"' : ''; ?>` will always return true because you check for 'Yes' and 'No'. This values are true for php. You have to set the values  0 or 1 in db or check do something like this:

`<?php echo $stuff["Completed"] == 'Yes' ? 'checked=" checked"' : ''; ?>`

...

`<?php echo $stuff["Completed"] == 'No' ? 'checked=" checked"' : ''; ?>`